# Migrating Openshift Online app from one account to another account

Tags: openshift

Is there any way I can migrate an app being deployed in one Openshift Online account to another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save and restore a snapshot of your OpenShift Online gear. This is described here, step by step:
[Migrating an Application to Another Gear](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/Migrating_an_Application_to_Another_Gear3.html)

However, as you will be saving the snapshot from one account and restoring to another, make sure to specify your login when doing so. Assuming you have completed setup for both accounts and have created a new 'newApp' on the new account, it will look like this:

```
$ rhc snapshot save oldApp -l oldAccount@login
Pulling down a snapshot of application 'oldApp' to oldApp.tar.gz ... done
$ rhc snapshot restore newApp -f oldAppSnapshot.tar.gz -l newAccount@login
Restoring from snapshot oldApp.tar.gz to application 'newApp' ... done
```

---

I recommend checking [developers.openshift.com](https://developers.openshift.com/) for similar administrative guides on how to work with OpenShift. The above linked article can be easily found there.